# Quit Python program when it hits memory limit

Tags: python, numpy

I have a couple of Python/Numpy programs that tend to cause the PC to freeze/run very slowly when they use too much memory. I can't even stop the scripts or move the cursor anymore, when it uses to much memory (e.g. 3.8/4GB)
Therefore, I would like to quit the program automatically when it hits a critical limit of memory usage, e.g. 3GB.

I could not find a solution yet. Is there a Pythonic way to deal with this, since I run my scripts on Windows and Linux machines.

Comment: You can tell your system to limit the process when starting it

Comment: I run my scripts on Windows and Linux machines - would be great if it works on both the same way.

Comment: Have a look at `psutil` for cross-platform memory usage, etc.: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could limit the process'es memory limit, but that is OS specific.

Another solution would be checking value of `psutil.virtual_memory()`, and exiting your program if it reaches some point.

Though OS-independent, the second solution is not Pythonic at all. Memory management is one of the things we have operating systems for.

Comment: I think psutil.virtual_memory() is what I was looking for. >> if (psutil.virtual_memory().free/1048576<1000): sys.exit()

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree that in general you want to do this from within the operating system - only because there's a reliability factor in having "possibly runaway code check itself for possibly runaway behavior"

If a hard and fast requirement is to do this WITHIN the script, then I think we'd need to know more about what you're actually doing.  If you have a single large data structure that's consuming the majority of the memory, you can use sys.getsizeof to identify how large that structure is, and throw/catch an error if it gets larger than you want.

But without knowing at least a little more about the program structure, I think it'll be hard to help...

Comment: +1, but be aware that `sys.getsizeof` doesn't reflect how much memory a numpy array takes up (among other things).

Comment: The programs import numpy arrays from various sources throughout the execution, which can sum up to sometimes just 1GB but sometimes 4GB. As Joe points out checking individual variables this way would not help too much.